# read.csv.sql() with missing values

Tags: r

I am trying to filter a very large file with real-time data - more than 93000 rows x 109 columns.
A lot of the columns have missing values so when I try to use the `read.csv.sql()` function from `sqldf` package, I get the following error:

```
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 1 did not have 109 elements
```

Is there any workaround such as `fill=TRUE` for `read.csv` that can be used with `read.csv.sql()`?

Comment: From which package is `read.csv.sql` function?

Comment: It's the sqldf package

Comment: You can use the `filter` argument. to transform the input before it's processed.  Please provide a minimal, complete, and reproducible example that anyone else can simply copy and paste into their session to run.  All library statements and inputs need to be included.  Cut down your data to the minimum needed to illustrate the problem.  Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve